# Want to subtract hour to hour, minutes to minutes, and seconds to seconds from between two dates

Tags: php, date

```
<?php
    $ts='2011-04-13 23:00:00';
    $ts1='2011-04-14 15:45:00';
    echo $addtime = date("h:i:s", mktime(date("h", $ts1)- date("h", $ts),date("i", $ts1)- date("i", $ts),date("s", $ts1)- date("s", $ts),0,0,0));
?>
```

It gives a result but it is not correct in many cases.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected result would be 16:45:00 for the given example, right? So you want the difference between the two given dates in hours:minutes:seconds.

```
<?php
    //initial strings
    $ts='2011-04-13 23:00:00'; 
    $ts1='2011-04-14 15:45:00';

    //converting to time
    $start = strtotime($ts);
    $end = strtotime($ts1);

    //calculating the difference
    $difference = $end - $start;

    //calculating hours, minutes and seconds (as floating point values)
    $hours = $difference / 3600; //one hour has 3600 seconds
    $minutes = ($hours - floor($hours)) * 60;
    $seconds = ($minutes - floor($minutes)) * 60;

    //formatting hours, minutes and seconds
    $final_hours = floor($hours);
    $final_minutes = floor($minutes);
    $final_seconds = floor($seconds);

    //output
    echo $final_hours . ":" . $final_minutes . ":" . $final_seconds;
?>
```

This gives me correct results. Hope I got your problem right!

Comment: But i am using variable $ts=$UpT; $ts1=$DownT; instead of 2012-11-18 03:00:05- 2012-11-05 12:46:13 it shows result 0:0:0

Comment: Well you didn't mention this in your question. What's the content of $UpT and $DownT? Is it a string like in the examples?

Comment: yes this is same $UpT=2012-11-18 03:00:05 and $DownT=2012-11-05 12:46:13

Comment: `2012-11-18 03:00:05` is not the same as `'2012-11-18 03:00:05'` (notice the ')! You HAVE to enclose your Date(-String) with ' in order to work with my solution. Your version (`$UpT=2012-11-18 03:00:05`) will get you syntax errors.  
Apart from this, the only differences are the names of the variables ($UpT vs $ts, $DownT vs $ts1), so how about changing the names or settings `$ts = $UpT; $ts1 = $DownT;` for example?

Comment: Just fiddled it: [phpfiddle.org/lite/code/uqh-rzv](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/uqh-rzv) - works great for me.

Comment: ok got it its not like that actually i added .'</br/>. thats why. thank you all